# WPF UserControl creating multiple layout choices

Tags: wpf, user-controls, templatebinding

I have a UserControl that I have various properties defined, so I can customise it for each copy that's on the screen. I have a path that uses a LinearGradientBrush fill. At present this is hard coded into the XAML. I already have the width and visibility of the path control as dependency objects and can easily modify these:

```
<Path 
    Visibility="{TemplateBinding PathAVisibility}"
    Width="{TemplateBinding PathALength}">
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,0.5" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="1,0.5">
            <GradientStop Color="#07FFFFFF" Offset="0.812"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Red"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0.993"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF956666" Offset="0.62"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>...
```

What I'd like to do is to create a few gradients as options that I can then select as properties in the WPF XAML designer. Something like "GradA" is with the red, "GradB" is Blue, but doesn't have the transparency, etc.

With the Visibility I can see the "Visible/Hidden/Collapsed" as options to choose from in the design view, and this is the kind of thing I'm after.

This is where I'm stuck. I don't even know what this would be called, or how to approach it.

Any pointers on which direction I should be looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `enum` to provide the fixed values you want in `Xaml`, then you can use the `PropertyChangedCallback` on that `enum` `DependencyProperty` to change the `Brush`.

Here is a **very quick** example.

Code:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public BrushType BrushType
    {
        get { return (BrushType)GetValue(BrushTypeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BrushTypeProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for BrushType.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BrushTypeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BrushType", typeof(BrushType), typeof(UserControl1)
        , new PropertyMetadata(BrushType.None, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnBrushTypeChanged)));

    private static void OnBrushTypeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var userControl = d as UserControl1;
        if (e.NewValue is BrushType)
        {
            userControl.MyBrush = userControl.FindResource(e.NewValue.ToString()) as Brush;
        }
    }

    public Brush MyBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(MyBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyBrushProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyBrush.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(null));

}

public enum BrushType
{
    None,
    BrushA,
    BrushB,
    BrushC
}
```

Xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFListBoxGroupTest.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushA" Color="Red" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushB" Color="Yellow" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushC" Color="Blue" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{Binding MyBrush}" />

</UserControl>
```

Usage:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <local:UserControl1 BrushType="BrushA" />
    <local:UserControl1 BrushType="BrushB" />
    <local:UserControl1 BrushType="BrushC" />
</StackPanel>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Ok, so I was mistaken in thinking that I had a usercontrol, but I don't I actually have a ResourceDictionary that I then have a control based on. I've plumbed in your code, which almost works a treat. The BrushA/B/C resources are not found. If I drop them in at the Page level as page resources then it compiles, but doesn't set the color. I'll mark your answer as right, as it's did work with what I asked. My fault I got my wires crossed. Can you advise on where I should be putting the SolidcolorBrush resources in the resource dictionary? Many thanks for the time you spent so far.

Comment: You can put the brushes anywhere in your control, if you are only using the Brushes on the Path you could place then in the <Path.Resources>, or in the parent container, if your not using UserControl what are you using, all FrameworkElements have thier own Resources

Comment: Thanks. I'll do a little more research into this over the weekend and see where it takes me.

Answer (score 0):

One nice feature that could minimize your coding effort here are ***Visual States***. Read about them [here](http://elijahm.ninjuro.com/2012/01/04/visual-states-in-wpf-4-0/). There's other mechanisms to achieve this as well. A combination of styles, templates and triggers would also work, but make it harder to access UI elements in your components code behind.

Comment: Thanks for that. It will probably help me when I come to do an image animation which I'm planning.